# What can be done about the calendar app closing itself on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, calendar

I have been using my calendar fine but this afternoon when I click on the tile it briefly opens (1 sec) and then closes itself. I have waited 30 mins, I have turned iPad off & back on and still no joy.

Answer (score 4):

This is how applications crash on iOS - so you may want to check your settings to see if your iPad is sending crash reports to Apple.

Settings App -> General -> Diagnostics & Usage

You can also look in the Data submenu from the above screen and scroll down to look for **LatestCrash.plist** and see if the date matches when your iCal quit.

In general, it's not possible (even as a developer) to read these reports without access to the iCal source code and you have some short term things you can do to isolate the issue further.

First is to remove any notifications (turn of WiFi and cellular data) and reboot the iPad. If iCal crashes, then it's due to the calendar data on the device and not some external cause. You can then remove your calendar information, account by account to clear up which account has the data corruption that is causing iCal to have a problem. Worst case, you will have to connect your iPad to a computer (iTunes) and force a sync to erase the calendar data on the iPad and replace it with data from the computer to clear the data that is causing the crash.

Apple will likely fix the crash (even with bad data - the program should handle it and let you know an event is broken or ignored and why) in the upcoming updates - but you can report the crash to add weight to this particular bug getting fixed.

You can also take an overkill (but faster) approach to erase all content and settings on the iPad and set it up again.

It's unlikely the data will come back corrupt from your calendar sources (or the backup) but if it does, at least you'll know a bit more about how to isolate which calendar is causing iCal to have problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i have isolated it to one particular month and going through your suggestions.

Comment: If you end up isolating it by hand, look up Binary search if you have more than ten items in that month to save time finding the problem. Also, attachments and attendees are generally more likely to be corrupt or cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the April 1st calendar crash. Delete whole day events on April 1st (and unsubscribe from calendars that give you public holidays on that day), and that should fix crashes that occur when you go to month view in March.

Answer (score 0):

Apple support tell me that the problem is known, their engineers are working on it and the temporary solution is to deselect the uk holiday calendar, and by implication any other calendar where events on April 1st are all day, and to change any all day events on April 1st on your own calendars to say 0100 to 2300.
It occurs that people might have several day events stretching over 31st March and 1st April which might also need amending.
Conspiracy paranoids might think the original programmer thought, ahah it's April Fools Day in 2013, but I guess it's more likely to be an unintended consequence of the 31st not having enough hours for a 24 hr all day event.

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar appears as a blank page and then closes you are unable to delete or change all day events from the 25 hours imposed by daylight saving to fewer hours.
In that case change your location a territory that does not use daylight saving, e.g. Most of Africa. When you reopen Calender you should be able to edit your all day events

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the subscription to DE Holidays events (German holidays) - and it fixed the problem, even though I have other all-day events listed on April 1.

Answer (score -4):

Drag the appointment to an empty date. Then you should be able to delete it. Worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure you are answering the right question?